# Javascript and `<>...</>` tags

Tags: javascript, cdata

So I recently discovered that I could use `<>...</>` tags in javascript in Firefox, which is handy when defining blocks of HTML or CSS.

```
GM_addStyle(<><![CDATA[
  .page { display: block }
  /* ... */
  td { vertical-align: top }
]]></>);
//...
div.innerHTML = <><![CDATA[
  <table class="section">
    <!-- ... -->
  </table>
]]></>;
```

But I'm not exactly sure what's going on, and I like understanding the syntax that I'm using.  What exactly does `<>...</>` return?  I noticed that the escaping works better when I enclose the contents in `<![CDATA[...]]>`, so what's happening there?  Is this Firefox only, or cross-browser?

I tried to look this up online, but ran into the normal google/symbol issue.  Plus, most of the results for [google CDATA javascript](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=CDATA+javascript&aq=f&aqi=g10&oq=) didn't seem relevant.

Comment: +1, Good question.  Don't fancy your chances for cross-browser compatibility here :-)  Good for a Firefox extension though.

Comment: @Andy E - it looks like it's in the javascript 1.6 standard, so it should work in anything that supports that.

Comment: It's called, ECMAScript for XML. I'm also surprised to see this, even though I've read this many times. Here's wikipedia info on this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML)

Comment: it (ECMAScript for XML) is an extension to JavaScript.  Gecko implements this in its own JavaScript 1.6 engine, but that doesn't necessarily mean others have - or ever will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the empty tags are just a way of writing a root element so that you have something in which to wrap a blob of XML. It's saying "Interpret the children of this root element as XML" and the single child in your case is saying "Interpret this child as a CDATA block."

Comment: So I can write random XML as a value in Javascript?  That seems odd.

Comment: Surprised me, too, when I first saw it. But that's how it works in Flex/Actionscript, and I don't think it's entirely coincidental. Caveat: I said "I believe" because I can't state this definitively.

Comment: Looks like you're right: ["E4X introduces a native XML object to the JavaScript language, and adds syntax for embedding literal XML documents in JavaScript code."](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X)

Comment: @rampion:  Great, so you use a feature that Firefox supports... what about the other browsers, like IE, Chrome/Safari, and Opera?

Comment: I don't think some browsers caught on it yet, unless it uses the Gecko Javascript engine, SpiderMonkey (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML)

Comment: No. You can just drop in a CDATA block. There's no reason to use `<>`

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Well, most of my javascript is GM-only, so I'm ok with it being FF-only.  And one of my original questions was whether it was FF-only, so that I'd know in which contexts it was available.

Comment: @Elijah Grey: Yes there is: ["For backwards compatibility, E4X defaults to ignoring comments and CDATA sections. You can add an e4x=1 argument to your <script>  tag to disable this restriction"](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X#Compatibility_issues)

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use an XMLList literal (`<>...</>`) with only one child, as it's handled as a single XML item anyways. Why not use just `<![CDATA[...]]>`? Also, `<![CDATA[...]]>` just returns an XML text node (`<![CDATA[]]>.nodeKind() === "text"`).

This is all part of [E4X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML), which is implemented by ActionScript 3 and both JavaScript engines.

Comment: Hmmm... just `<![CDATA[]]>` was a syntax error in FF3.6 (just plugging it into the Error Console).  I'm not sure how it would evaluate in a Greasemonkey script, but the mozilla docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X) say you need to set a special attribute to prevent <![CDATA[...]]> from being treated specially in a normal <source> tag.

Comment: This is because you are evaluating JavaScript 1.5, not 1.6 in the error console. CDATA problems will not occur in a greasemonkey script as it's not an inline HTML script. Add `;e4x=1` to the end of the script's `type`. Or better yet, use this shell which lets you use E4X: http://code.eligrey.com/shell/shell.html

Answer (score 1):

As Elijah said, it's E4X syntax that won't work anywhere but Mozilla. You don't appear to be using it for anything to do with XML, just relying on the implicit `toString` method of the `XML` object being the same as the original markup. ECMA-357 (the E4X spec) doesn't specify the exact parse and serialisation rules for XML, so it doesn't guarantee eg. to remove the `<![CDATA[` markers for you. IMO relying on this even just on Firefox is questionable.

In any case it doesn't really solve the problems of escaping content for use inside a `script` block... in particular, the `</` sequence is still invalid in HTML4, the whole lot is invalid in XHTML, and you would still have to worry about the sequences `</script` and `]]>` in the content. So you haven't really gained a lot... at best, you've got yourself a multi-line string in external scripts, at the expense of support for all the other browsers. I don't think it's really worth it.